# Capturing HTTP traffic in Fiddler while using TestDriven.NET

Tags: unit-testing, fiddler, testdriven.net

I've been writing some unit tests that use a web service to retrieve information from the web. When I run my code from a console application, I can monitor the calls via Fiddler and see what's being requested and the server response.

When I make these same service calls by running a unit test with TestDriven.NET, the calls are not shown in the calls through Fiddler.

Does anybody what I would have to do to configure this, so that I can monitor the calls with Fiddler while running unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that when I configured my test application (the console app) and my unit tests, that I configured one using SSL and one not. By default, Fiddler does not decode or list HTTPS traffic. I simply had to enable this feature and it started working great.

Comment: Don't forget the "...from all processes" setting :-)

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the proxy config. It looks like this: http://gurustop.net/blog/2010/08/10/visual-studio-2010-extension-manager-online-gallery-behind-internet-proxy/ has a suggestion for how to do that. See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DotNet for more.

Comment: interesting... I didn't know that VS by default doesn't use proxy settings for it's add-ins, however my problem here isn't with a proxy. I actually figured out that I wasn't capturing HTTPS traffic. When I configured my tests and the console app (I did them at separate times), I configured one to connect via SSL and one not to.

Comment: I followed the steps in the first link to update my devenv.exe.config and I have decode SSL checked in Fiddler, but it still won't show my traffic. I am trying to hit a web service (.svc) in my dev environment from an NUnit test run locally on my machine and it does actually hit the endpoint, but nothing ever shows up in Fiddler. Any ideas?

Comment: I found my problem! When setting Fiddler to decode HTTPS traffic, make sure to set it for "all processes", not just "browser traffic".